# Infinite call to python class variable

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables, infinite-recursion

So, I'm fairly new to Python, and I am trying to learn how the OOP paradigm works there.
One thing that confuses me at this stage are the class variables. To be more specific, consider the following example taken from the *Python 3 Object-Oriented Programming* book by Dusty Phillips (*Chapter 3 - When objects are alike*):

```
class Contact:
    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
```

So, here we see a simple example of a class that has the class variable `all_contacts` which is an empty list. Besides that there are two instance variables, `name` and `email`.
Now, if we were to create two different instances of the class `Contact`, e.g.

```
c1 = Contact('John', 'john@gmail.com')
c2 = Contact('Mark', 'mark@yahoo.com')
```

there are two ways how we can access properties `name` and `email`, i.e.

1. `c1.name`
2. `c1.all_contacts[0].name`

But this is where I have a problem - `all_contacts` is a class variable, meaning that it is common to all instances of the class `Contact`. Not only that it is common to all instances, but due to the way how this list is being populated, there is nothing that prevents me from doing this:
`c1.all_contacts[1].name`
which gives me the `name` property of the instance `c2`.
In fact, it seems that I can go deep as much as I want:
`c1.all.contacts[0].all_contacts[1].all_contacts[0]...`
In other words, I am worried if in Python we have a class with a class variable as a list and then in the initializer method we store `self` to that list, are we then creating a structure that can reference itself infinite many times? Is there some kind of workaround for this?

I would really appreciate if anyone can comment on this behavior.

Kind regards

Comment: In this example, Contact represents both an individual contact *and* a container for all contacts. That's the confusion.

Comment: "if in Python we have a class with a class variable as a list and then in the initializer method we store self to that list, are we then creating a structure that can reference itself infinite many times?" We are. Why is that a problem? There is already a *built-in* example of this behaviour: `'a'[0][0][0][0][0]` (ad nauseam).

Comment: It's *accessible* by all objects; that doesn't mean it is *part* of those instances. `c1.all_contacts` resolves to `Contact.all_contacts` only because there is no instance attribute with the same name.

Comment: If you intend this as a technical question ("will it cause the interpreter to crash" etc.) then no, there is no problem. If you intend it as a *design* question ("should I write code like this?") or a general curiousity ("how is it possible for the interpreter to implement this behaviour?"), then it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does the class `Contact` need to have constant knowledge of all contacts that have ever existed? That seems like an odd design choice.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I agree, I think the confusion here is more caused by the author asking readers to consider an example that doesn't seem to make any practical sense. I've seen that before and it's very frustrating and distracting.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
I saw it as a technical issue since it seemed to me that in this way we could either crash the interpreter or get it stuck, because I do not understood if and what are the side-effects of such coding approach. The first thing I thought of was possible memory explosion or some kind of infinite loop when referencing the class instance via c1.all_contacts[index].all_contacts[index]. ... .name. Is there then an explanation why does Python interpreter tolerates this behavior?

Comment: It's the same as asking why it is possible in C to follow a closed cycle of pointers manually as far as you like. There is no infinite loop because the code is explicitly indicating how much iteration to do. There is no memory explosion because no memory is allocated, it is only looked up.

Comment: @Z4-tier
Indeed, this confusion did arose from odd choice of example, because I do not see why would we ever do a bookkeeping in this manner.

Comment: @ŽeljkoJelić If you feel you have a good understanding of the properties and behavior of class and instance variables, I would suggest you move past this example and don't get hung up on it. It's not well framed.